# "Escaping" Linux kernel version in latex

Tags: equations, formatting

I'm trying to include a kernel version info (i.e. `\texttt{2.6.40.4-5.fc15.x86_64}`) in my LaTeX document. However, LaTeX keeps trying to put it into "math-text" ("Missing $ inserted" and so on).

How do I escape this text, so that I can place it as text, not an equation?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is the underscore.  TeX uses that as a special character to denote subscripts, as in `x_1,x_2`.  TeX assumes that wherever it encounters an underscore the author means it to be a subscript.

Fortunately, this behaviour can be overridden.  Even more fortunately, you don't need to know how this is done since it is already solved for you!  LaTeX provides the `\verb` (short for "verbatim") command which typesets its contents in the `\texttt` family and sorts out all the "special" characters so that they appear *as is*.  A way to use it for you would be:

```
\verb+2.6.40.4-5.fc15.x86_64+
```

The `+` is a delimiter that you yourself can choose, so if the string has `+` in it then you can choose something else, such as `*`.  Just make sure that the delimiter is not something that appears in the string that you want to typeset.

Answer (score 11):

To complete other answers, I should mention that if the text is entered manually (not programmatically generated), `\_` or `\textunderscore` can be used to easily obtain the underscore:

```
\texttt{2.6.40.4-5.fc15.x86\_64}
\texttt{2.6.40.4-5.fc15.x86\textunderscore 64}
```

I suppose `\_` is as close to *escaping* as you can get :-)

Comment: (for completeness: even if programmatically generated, you could pipe through sed or similar to find/replace such instances)

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to run the shell command from inside LaTeX; for example, here is how to get the output of `uname -a`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\uname{{\ttfamily\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials
  \catcode` =10 \pdfprimitive\input|"uname -a" }\unskip}

\begin{document}
\uname
\end{document}
```

For this it's necessary to run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option.

A more general version might be:

```
\def\syscommand#1{{\ttfamily\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials
  \catcode` =10 \pdfprimitive\input|"#1" }\unskip}
```

and `\syscommand{uname -a}` would give the same result as before. Use with ***great*** care.